# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS from .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

This is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.foo\.org$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/foo\.org\/en\/" [R=301,L]
```

When I open foo.org, I get this error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. My .htaccess file has always worked until now. Probably something has changed in the Apache configuration of the provider of my hosting. I also updated my WordPress version to 4.4.1, but I don't think that it could be an issue...

How can I Fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?foo\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /en/ [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Yes, it works!! The redirect seems a bit slow. Could it depend on the rule?

Comment: No rules don't take any time to execute, it might be some network thing.